# Creating scriptblocks from string

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

Here is what I am trying to get to work in a scriptblock

```
$scriptblock={
for /f "tokens=14" %i in ('"ipconfig | findstr IPv4"') do set ip=%i

nslookup %ip%
}
```

Everytime though I get

> Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s): "At line:4 char:4
>   + for /f "tokens=14" %i in ('"ipconfig | findstr IPv4"') do set ip=%i
>   +    ~ Missing opening '(' after keyword 'for'. " At line:1 char:1
>   + $scriptblock=[scriptblock]::create($scriptblock)
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParseException

I have tried setting it to a here string first then using `[scriptblock]::create()`, but still get the same thing.

How do I get this into the scriptblock?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Getting your hostname? Why do you mix batch statements and PowerShell?

Comment: It is going to be run on a lot of server 2003 which may or may not have powershell.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try to mix batch and PowerShell commands. To get the IPv4 address try this:

```
$ip = (ipconfig | Foreach {if ($_ -match 'IPv4 address.*?:\s+(.*)') {$matches[1]}})[0]
```

Of if you are on Windows 8 or higher, you can use:

```
Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -AddressState Preferred
```

Comment: Sure, but this command is going to be run on several 2003 servers which may or may not have powershell....

Comment: @CRad14 if a server doesn't have PowerShell, how do you expect it to recognize a PowerShell construct e.g. `$scriptblock={...}`?

Comment: I don't, but I will be using Invoke-VMscript to pass the contents of the scriptblock to the OS.

Comment: Can you just use the `-ScriptText` parameter to pass text instead of a scriptblock?